# Trying to access a list in a file and use it as a string

Tags: python, string, list, file

I would like to be able to use a list in a file to 'upload' a code to the program.

NotePad file:

```
savelist = ["Example"]
namelist = ["Example2"]
```

Python Code:

```
with open("E:/battle_log.txt", 'rb') as f:
    gamesave = savelist[(name)](f)
    name1 = namelist [(name)](f)
    print ("Welcome back "+name1+"! I bet you missed this adventure!")
    f.close()
    print savelist
    print namelist
```

I would like this to be the output:

```
Example
Example2
```

Comment: And what's not going according to plan?

Comment: don't close the file inside a context manager. That's the context manager's job -- just leave the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to serialize a program state, the re-load it later! You should consider using a database instead, or even simply `pickle`

```
import pickle

savelist = ["Example"]
namelist = ["Example2"]

obj_to_pickle = (savelist, namelist)

with open("path/to/savefile.pkl", 'wb') as p:
    pickle.dump(obj_to_pickle, p)
    # save data

with open('path/to/savefile.pkl', 'rb') as p:
    obj_from_pickle = pickle.load(p)
    savelist, namelist = obj_from_pickle
    # load data
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

- Save your notepad file with the .py extension and import it. As long as it contains valid python code, everything will be accessible
- Load the text as a string and execute it (e.g., via eval())
- Store the information in an easy to read configuration file (e.g., YAML) and parse it when you need it
- Precompute the data and store it in a pickle file

The first two are risky if you don't have control over who will provide the file as someone can insert malicious code into the inputs.

Comment: follow advice from @Amack  

BTW f.close() is not needed as 'with' statement will autoclose the file object

Answer (score 0):

You could simply import it as long the file is in the same folder as the one your program is in. Kinda like this:

```
import example.txt
```

or:

```
from example.txt import*
```

Then access it through one of two ways. The first one:

```
print Example.savelist[0]
print Example.namelist[0]
```

The second way:

```
print savelist[0]
print namelist[0]
```